# Memory Leak When Updating Excel Chart Every 1s

Tags: excel, vba

I modify the values of a SeriesCollection every 1s in the following way:

```
 Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "={0}"
```

This causes my memory to increase continuously which makes me think there is a leak. Why?

I am currently using Excel 2007.

Comment: Not sure about the memory leak, but is there a reason you're doing this?  It might be possible to get the same result with setting a series to zero values.  Is it to force an update every second?

Comment: Hi Bryan, the code above is just a test conducted understand why my actual macro had a memory leak. In my actual macro,  I am periodically reading from a log file and updating the excel charts according to the extracted data points. This is at an interval of 1s. I noticed that the memory usage reaches 900 MB after 12 hours.

Comment: Does it behave better if you dump your values into a worksheet range, which the chart series is linked to, and let the updating of the chart happen automatically when new data is introduced?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with SeriesCollection updates is that they are very inefficient. In typical use cases it's inconsequential, however when excessive/rapid updates occur between workbook open/close you'll not only see memory inflation, but screen update lag too.

This is going to seem a little counterintuitive at first but it is much less resource intensive.

It will run 30,000 cycles in under two seconds on my machine, with less than 1MB of additional memory used vs. several minutes and 50MB in just 1000 cycles using SeriesCollection.  That's a little over 8 continuous hours at 1 update/second (with screen updating ON) so I hope it will work for you.

```
Dim arrTableVals() As Integer
Dim iUbound As Integer
Dim iArrCount As Integer

iUbound = 20
'Resize your array with iUbound derived from elsewhere in your sub
ReDim arrTableVals(iUbound, 0) As Integer
'Populate the array where sheets/charts do not update
For iArrCount = 0 To iUbound
    arrTableVals(iArrCount, 0) = iArrCount + 1
Next
'Assign the array to the chart source range
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").Range("A2:A" & iUbound + 2).Value = arrTableVals
```

Excel has a very simple way of handling memory during VBA execution when it is interacting with worksheet data.  It purges all history at runtime, and doesn't start storing again until completion (which is why Undo dissappears).  I suspect that SeriesCollections are exempt from this, since they can be updated separate from a table.